# How to assign AJAX JSON response to jquery variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

When some one clicks the category button an AJAX request send to `category.php` in this php file i am encoding a JSON response.

**Jquery Onclick Function**

```
$('#Category').change(function(){            
    var j;
  $.ajax({
   url:'categories.php',
   success: function(results){
      var obj = JSON.parse(status);
       alert(obj);
   }                
  });            
});
```

**category.php File**

```
<option value="" selected="">Select Sub Category</option>
<option value="Cars">Cars</option>
<option value="Motorbikes & Scooters">Motorbikes & Scooters</option>

    $status = array('type' => 'yes');
    echo json_encode($status);
```

Now how to assign **yes** to a JQuery variable on AJAX success? i tried some codes (in Above JQuery codes) but that didn't work please suggest me a solution.

Comment: What you get when you `alert(results)`?

Comment: why are you not just passing "yes" ??

Comment: `var v = obj.type;` ?

Comment: @urfusion nothin!!

Comment: There's no need to use `parse()` method, add this setting `dataType:'json'` to your AJAX request. `dataType` is the type of data you're expecting back from the server.

Comment: @user466061 : `alert(results)` is alerting ?

Comment: The only correct solution is to fix your server side script so that it doesn't output JSON and HTML. I mean, how did you plan to access the HTML anyway? That makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

According to your, you are getting the response from `php` page in `results` not in `status` and `results` itself is a `jquery` variable. So change `status` to `results`.

```
$('#Category').change(function () {
    var j;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'categories.php',
        success: function (results) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(status);
            alert(obj);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: something i didn't mentioned from that category.php page not only encoded JSON response coming, there is some other <option> tages for select box also laoding so i am getting an error

Comment: @user466061: Then fix your server script to only return JSON.

Comment: @felixKling i need both encoded JSON and those <option> tags

Comment: @urfusion this is the error i am getting, VM34325:4 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 46

Comment: @user466061: Then send the HTML as part of  the JSON as well. Or better: Generate the `<option>` elements in JavaScript from data you return (instead of building them on the server side). You cannot return two different kinds of data with the same response and process it in a reasonable way.

Comment: @user466061 : can you paste full code of your `categories.php`?

Comment: @urfusion it contains lots of codes more than 250 lines

Comment: then do as @FelixKling told you.

Comment: @urfusion is it possible to check if the results contains the word 'yes'? if can please give me a code

Comment: @user466061 : if your `category.php` is not attached with any `post` call then you can put a check of `post` like `if($_POST) {   $status = array('type' => 'yes');
    echo json_encode($status);}`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this problem.. thanks for the effort guys..

```
$('#Category').change(function () {        
    $.ajax({
        url: 'categories.php',
        success: function (results) {
            if (results.indexOf("yes") >= 0) {
              var j = 'yes';
              alert(j);
             }
        }
    });
});
```